# Return boolean on the basis of multiple condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a use-case where I want to return boolean value from the function

```
private boolean checkStatus(String param) {
  return param != null ?  randomBool() : true;
}

private boolean randomBool() {
  // return true or false on the basis of some condition 
}
```

I am getting complaint issue over `true` statement. What could be the other way to achieve the same?

Sonar issue: Redundant Boolean literals should be removed from expressions to improve readability.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sonar issue "Redundant Boolean literals should be removed from expressions to improve readability."

Comment: Sounds like a code scanner warning, not a compilation error with your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your code to the next:

```
param == null || randomBool()
```